# How to capture dynamic URL part to return a list in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I need to code an API which will be used by dropdowns in a react form. There are multiple dropdowns and exposed API url also follow similar pattern. For example -

```
/api/trend/foo?bar=0
/api/trend/foo?bar=1
/api/trend/baz?bar=0
/api/trend/baz?bar=0
/api/trend/fish?foss=1
/api/trend/baz?foss=2
```

So it boils down to `/api/trend/{table}?{filter}={val}` which will return a list `{col}`, which further boils down to `SELECT col FROM table WHERE filter=val`

I don't want to write multiple functions for same pattern. I am looking for something like this

```
# in views.py
def dropdown_api(request, table, filter):
    # fire the SQL statement
    # get the result in a df/list
    # serialize the result
    # return the response to consume by react

# in urls.py
path('api/trend/{table}?{filter}={val}', views.dropdown_api) #something like this to capture the dynamic url content
```

Comment: use `re_path` for describing url patterns in regex form. There you can capture the dynamic part and use it in your views ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `re_path` for capturing the dynamic part in url with regex.

```
urlpatterns = [
  re_path(r'^api/trend/(?P<table>\w+)/?$', views.dropdown_api, name='bio'),
]

# in views.py
def dropdown_api(request, table):
    # fire the SQL statement
    # get the result in a df/list
    # serialize the result
    # return the response to consume by react
    print(request.params) # passed params
```

Comment: Not able to parse the passed params, it is giving `{}`. I used `content_params` as `params` is not a valid attribute.